# Put to Key Value on HBase

Tags: hbase

I am trying to convert a `Put` object to a `KeyValue` objects.
How can I achieve that on HBase? I have looked at the source code but didn't found a way to do that.
My `Put` object contains rowkey and 2 columns (A,B columns).

Thanks for helpers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Put with 2 columns is not a Key Value, but 2 Key Values.

Check this method in Put class:

```
KeyValue createPutKeyValue(byte[] family, byte[] qualifier, long ts, byte[] value) {
  return new KeyValue(this.row, family, qualifier, ts, KeyValue.Type.Put, value);
}
```

KeyValue contains cell information - a key, column family with column, timestamp and data.

So for your case

```
List<KeyValue> keyValues = new ArrayList<>();
for (Map.Entry<byte[], List<Cell> entry : put.getFamilyCellMap()) {
    byte[] cf = entry.getKey();
    List<Cell> cells = entry.getValue();
    for (Cell cell : cells) {
      // get row, column, ts and value using Cell api
      keyValues.add(new KeyValue(...));
    }
}
```